# connect to database from external server

Tags: php, mysql, server

i have a website running on a freedomain on 000webhost.com (server A) when i need to use databases. for the freeplan, they give you only 2 databases witch craches all the time! they are not working!

also, i have another website on other freedomain on freewebhostingarea.com (server B) witch didn't accept creating sessions (so i can't work with it) but they have a good database.

So, what i want, i'm asking if i can use the second database's (server B) in the first website (server A).

both of them, had the same host: "localhost" to access to databases.

Comment: Since both of the services are free shared-hosting sites, I doubt that they let you connect to their DB server from outside world.

Comment: "localhost" is useless information. EVERY networked machine is its own localhost.

Comment: so isn't possible to do it?

Comment: @MarcB i found others free domains gives you a link to reach the database directly

Comment: It totally depends on this hosting services.  I will say, you kind of get what you pay for with free services, so I wouldn't invest a bunch of time in creating a convoluted architecture based on them.

Comment: you pay nothing and complain it doesn't work

Comment: Theoretically yes, as long as on the good database you can create an account that is allowed to connect from a remote machine and the code server does not block port 3306 to stop you doing this, and you can amend the connections string to use the ip address of the good database server. ___It might be cheaper to pay a few bucks and get a decent host___